How to perform an action when the NavigationLink label is tapped?
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var num = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    Text("Number: \(num)")
                }, label: {
                    Text("tap here").onTapGesture {
                       num += 1
                        print("\(num)")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

In this code, when I tap on the 'tap here' NavigationLink, it is not navigating to a new page. It gets stuck in onTapGesture and just increments the value on tap.
Is there is any way to use the NavigationLink for both navigation and action?

Use a button, not a navigationLink.  That way the action can increment the property and then push the destination onto the nav stack.

You could try this approach using simultaneousGesture to perform some action as well as navigate to your destination view.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var num = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    Text("Number: \(num)")
                }, label: {
                    Text("tap here")
                })
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded { // <--- here
                    num += 1
                    print("\(num)")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}


You can perform the associated action in .onAppear:
NavigationStack {
    NavigationLink("tap here") {
        Text("Number: \(num)")
            .onAppear {
                num += 1
                print("\(num)")
            }
    }
}

